# mapping excel data to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, excel

how to mapping excel data column name to mysql data field?
and mapping between excel data column name and mysql data field name and getting the excel data from excel file

Comment: what are you trying to achive here ? if you whant only to import excel data into mysql then you can use phpMyAdmin , save you're excel file as CSV then use phpMyAdmin import feature .

Answer (score 0):

use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) with a delimited text file (save the Excel as .txt).  You choose exactly which columns map to which fields.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the method I use for getting data from Excel to MySQL: [Excel to MySQL using Add-ins](http://venerableagents.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/excel-add-ins/)

Answer (score 0):

save your excel file as csv 
and type the query 
load local data infile "your file path" into your table name
fields terminated by ","
lines terminated by "\n";`