# import excel data into mysql database

Tags: php

mapping excel data to mysql table field and that data I want script.
suppose in excel file there are 3 column name,age,company,department and mysql table there field name,age,company so both mapping of excel and mysql table data field and insert the value into mysql database.

So at that time both data field map and so department field its not in mysql so that value are not inserted and only mapping value are inserted in mysql table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mapping excel data to mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593436/mapping-excel-data-to-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) class for reading the MS Excel files. Keep in mind that it can use much memory on big files. You can also save the Excel file to CSV format and use the PHP function fgetcsv().